# Layout children frozen after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-animation

I am animating a ConstraintLayout off screen, then back into screen. However, after animating the ConstraintLayout back into view the child elements (EditTexts and Button) are frozen.

I believe it is because the layout is just showing an image of itself, with the actual elements behind. How can I get the layout to 'redraw'?

Here is an example of the issue:

[image]

Here is my code:

slide_out_left.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="false" >
        <translate android:duration="200" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    </set>
```

slide_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="200" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

View code:

```
public void slideCreateFormOutToLeft() {

    Animation slideOutLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivityContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left);
    slideOutLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            createTaskViewFormContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    createTaskViewFormContainer.startAnimation(slideOutLeft);
}

public void slideCreateFormInFromLeft() {

    createTaskViewFormContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation slideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivityContext(), R.anim.slide_in_left);
    slideInLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    createTaskViewFormContainer.startAnimation(slideInLeft);

}
```

Comment: Can you give a full code on your screen?, I have tested your code above, no problem. Btw, I'm suspicious that you set INVISIBLE instead of GONE on your "Record a Message" popup screen.

Comment: Really? Very interested to know what I have done wrong! I have added my code as a gist, it's a big mid-testing mess though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view)

> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only
>   modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For
>   instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the
>   button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click
>   the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to
>   handle this.

So the Buttons and EditTexts inside the createTaskViewFormContainer is not in the vicinity of your click area. This is a problem with ViewAnimation and it is recommended to use PropertyAnimation instead, like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

createTaskViewFormContainer.animate().translationX(-screenWidth).start();
```

To bring the view back:

```
createTaskViewFormContainer.animate().translationX(0).start();
```